# Firefox extentions fails to install with org.openqa.selenium.firefox.UnableToCreateProfileException: java.io.IOException

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

Here are the two sceanrios

1. Setup on my windows machine
2. Setup on the cloud linux based

Locally on windows machine everything works as expected.

On cloud linux based when trying to do 'File file_name= new File("/opt/selenoid/firefox.xpi")' I  java.io.FileNotFoundException: \opt\selenoid\firefox.xpi (The system cannot find the path specified) and it thrown from FirefoxProfile creation
[image]

When I add space at the end I get the following  org.openqa.selenium.firefox.UnableToCreateProfileException: java.io.IOException: Can only install from a zip file, an XPI or a directory
I get the same error on windows if I try to add space at the end.
[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this issue or why would I get fileNotFoundExpection

Comment: try backslash `new File("/opt/selenoid/firefox.xpi")` here and share your code also.

Comment: I get the same error of file not found